# Apply class to <p> tag after an image

Tags: html, css

I have a blog where there's multiple images followed by a line as caption in the following manner:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Some Text above has <em>style</em> and so I can't use `em` style.</p>
    <img class="alignnone" src="header.jpg">
    <p><em>Photo Courtesy Of Donald Trump</em></p>
    <p>Some Text</p><p>Some Text</p><p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

I want to change the first `<p>` tag after the image and tried the following CSS but it didn't work.

```
img:first-child > p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Tried this too:

```
img > p:first-child em {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Tried this but that changes the first line or anywhere else where I have previously used `<em>` and so this method doesn't work either although I get what I want.

```
.content p > em {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

How do I detect the `<img>` tag which is followed by `<p><em>caption here</em></p>`.

Comment: Are you looking for `img + p`?

Comment: YES!!! Just got it done with `.alignnone +  p > em `. I really don't know how I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS selector you're looking for here is `+`, the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).  For example:

```
img + p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this css selector

```
.alignnone + p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it done with

```
.alignnone +  p > em {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Will close this question.

Comment: This was my answer, common courtesy is to wait for me to answer it.

Comment: I actually got it right after posting this question and came back to this post to see your comment. Please post it as an answer. I'll mark yours correctly. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
img:first-of-type + p { /*/Css rules /*/}
```